# difference between linq compound from clause and inner join

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
var orders =
    from c in customers
    from o in c.Orders
    where o.Total < 500.00M
    select new { c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.Total };
```

What is the difference between using 2 from clause and making inner join? Which one do I use? And When?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create the join for you.  If you are using LINQ to SQL you can to a `.ToString()` on `orders` and you will see the generated SQL statement.  If these were from two different sets it would create a cross join but because it is a child relation it will create the correct inner join for you.

Comment: So, this is different syntax for inner join. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is still an inner join.